# Parsec for balanced brackets

Tags: haskell

As an exercise in learning to use Parsec, I'm writing a parser that validates balanced brackets. I'm only worried about the pairs `()`, `[]`, and `{}`, but can't get my parser to handle multiple bracket groups inside the first.

I'm testing against a number of test cases pulled from [the bracket-push exercise](https://github.com/exercism/haskell/tree/master/exercises/bracket-push) from exercism.io, but notable edge cases are:

```
isBalanced "" = True
isBalanced "(some[nonsense]with)brackets" = True
isBalanced "}{" = False   -- reversed brackets no good.
isBalanced "{}}" = False  -- extra ending brackets no good either.
```

and my parser looks like:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char

hasMatchingBrackets = go >> eof
  where
  go = skipMany (noneOf "[{()}]")
        >> optional (
           between (char '(') (char ')') go
       <|> between (char '{') (char '}') go
       <|> between (char '[') (char ']') go )
        >> skipMany (noneOf "[{()}]")

isBalanced :: String -> Bool
isBalanced xs = case parse hasMatchingBrackets "isBalanced" xs of
                  Right _ -> True
                  Left  _ -> False
```

My parser as-is works for all the above cases, but the following test case that should pass does not

```
isBalanced "([{}({}[])])" = True  -- Fails with the parser above!
```

I've identified the problem as my alternation of `between`s only allowing one occurrence of `go` between a pair of brackets, and the open paren in `[{}(...` makes two, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried slapping `skipMany1` in front of `go`, to read

```
    between (char '(') (char ')') (skipMany1 go)
<|> ...etc
```

but I get the error:

> *** Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `many` is the right solution, but you need to get rid of the `optional` first.

The problem is that, as the error message says, `optional` can match the empty string and the problem with that is that `many` repeats the match for as long as the given parser can still find a match. If a parser matches the empty string, it'll always find a match (the empty string), so it'll never stop looping. So this is disallowed to prevent infinite loops.

Since `many` can already match zero occurrences, the `optional` isn't needed and you can just get rid of it.

Comment: This is it exactly, thanks! I'm having an issue with a further test case, but if I can't figure it out on my own I'll post a new question (no time to dig into it now -- lunch break is over!)